# class types as private members, MVP?

Tags: c++

Because of the most vexing parse, if you have a private member definition in a class header which is a class type like this:

```
box newBox;
```

and box has a constructor that accepts no arguments, does that mean you have to either make it a pointer or a reference type?

how do you get around this problem? It seems inelegant to be able to declare some classes this way but not the one's that accept no arguments. or am I misunderstanding something?

because as far as I understand it, if it accepts no arguments, then this is not only a definition, but initialisation as well.

```
class whatever
{
private:
    box newBox; //is this not allowed because of the most vexing parse? because it's a
                //header file and because of the MVP this is initialisation as well? or
                //am I getting confused about something?
};

class box
{
public:
    box();
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse @SirYakalot: I think your question has nothing to do with the MVP. Show a code example of ambiguity. Your example is not ambiguous, but it depends on the context so it's a meaningless example.

Comment: @SirYakalot: You could have just edited your previous question instead of deleting it.

Comment: I felt like it was just going in the wrong direction, so I made a less confused one

Comment: Your code won't even compile; how can we discuss ambiguity? Also I still have no idea where the ambiguity could be. How could `box newBox;` be interpreted as a function declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works just fine:

```
struct Foo {
}

struct Bar {
    Foo foo;
}
```

No MVP, no ambiguity. Everything is fine. Inside a class-declaration `Foo foo;` is a member-declaration. It cannot be initialized there, initialization is done (explicitly or implicitly) in the constructor (of `Bar` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If the only constructor accepts no arguments, this is *the* canonical constructor that's called every time you construct an instance of the class which has `newBox` as an element. It's still always a new `box` object, though it'll always look the same.

---

You can test it this way:

```
class foo {
 public:
  foo() {
    std::cout << "Constructed a foo.\n";
  }
};

class bar{
  foo afoo;
 public:
  bar() {}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Request new bar: ";
  bar bar1;
  std::cout << "Request another new bar: ";
  bar bar2;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Request new bar: Constructed a foo.
Request another new bar: Constructed a foo.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong about your `whatever` class, besides that you need to move the definition of `box` before that of `whatever`, so that `box` can be used there. When you create an instance of `whatever`, the `newBox` will be initialized with the default constructor of the `box` class.

If you want to be explicit about the initialization or customize it in some way, you have to add a constructor to the `whatever` class. For example:

```
class whatever {
private:
    box newBox;
public:
    whatever() : newBox() {
       // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the most vexing parse:

```
box newBox();
```

This is not:

```
box newBox;
```

Comment: 'This is not' Yes it is. But only if it appears in a function body.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: `box newBox;` is not ambiguous, even in a function body. Or maybe you misunderstood?